# Run multiple files in terminal simultaneously

Tags: macos, bash

I need to write a batch/script file that will run the following files:

```
server.js
client.js
```

I want to run server.js only once but the client.js I want to run multiple times. I need the scripts to run simultaneously.

Is it possible?

Comment: Search pm2 or forever. The former would be my personal choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

node ./server.js &

for i in `seq 0 5`; do
    node ./client.js &
done
```

Comment: Just FYI, it is `/bin/bash` on OSX just the same.

Comment: Why do you need a subshell and `seq` and ugly backquotes while `for i in {0..5}` or `for ((i=0;i<=5;++i))` will do as well (and more efficiently)?

Comment: (Long religious debate removed.)